# Export all charts in an Excel-workbook to a windows folder

Tags: vba, charts, export, batch-rename, suffix

I tried to run the following macro. Seems to work (I don`t have any error) but in the end only an empty folder opens (no picture exported). Please, help me with any advice! I am a beginner in VBA. Thank you very much!

```
Sub ExportAllCharts()
    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim objWindowsFolder As Object
    Dim strWindowsFolder As String
    Dim objSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim objChartObject As Excel.ChartObject
    Dim objChart As Excel.Chart

    'Select a Windows folder
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objWindowsFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select a Windows folder:", 0, "")

    If Not objWindowsFolder Is Nothing Then
       strWindowsFolder = objWindowsFolder.self.Path & "\"

       For i = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count To 1 Step -1
           Set objSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i)

           If objSheet.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
              For Each objChartObject In objSheet.ChartObjects
                  Set objChart = objChartObject.Chart
                  objChart.Export strWindowsFolder & objChart.Name & ".png"
              Next
          End If
       Next

       'Open the windows folder
       Shell "Explorer.exe" & " " & strWindowsFolder, vbNormalFocus
   End If
End Sub
```

[Source code link](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/3-methods-to-batch-export-all-charts-in-an-excel-workbook-to-a-windows-folder/)

Now I`m trying to find a solution to export all the charts with the **worksheet name + a suffix**.
I wish I could insert the desired suffix (the same for all worksheets) into a pop-up window.

I have this code that **renames all the worksheets**, but I need to adapt it to rename them only **partially**. I thought maybe I could incorporate it into the initial macro.

```
Sub ChangeWorkSheetName()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "Write the new Worksheets Name"
NewName = Application.InputBox("Name", xTitleId, "", Type:=2)
j = 1
For i = 1 To Application.Sheets.Count
If Application.Sheets(i).Visible Then
Application.Sheets(i).Name = NewName & j
j = j + 1
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Can anyone give me a suggestion? Thank you very much!

Comment: Works for me.  Are your charts on chart sheets, or embedded on worksheets?  This only exports the second type of chart.

Comment: Are you sure that your workbook contains any chart...? Please, insert the next code line, immediately after `Set objSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i)`: `Debug.Print objSheet.ChartObjects.Count`. Does it return any number bigger than 0 in Immediate window?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to include charts on chart sheets you need a second loop:

```vb
Sub ExportAllCharts()
    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim objWindowsFolder As Object
    Dim strWindowsFolder As String
    Dim objSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim objChartObject As Excel.ChartObject
    Dim objChart As Excel.Chart
    
    'Select a Windows folder
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objWindowsFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select a Windows folder:", 0, "")
    
    If Not objWindowsFolder Is Nothing Then
        strWindowsFolder = objWindowsFolder.self.Path & "\"
        
        'charts on chart sheets
        For Each objChart In ThisWorkbook.Charts
            objChart.Export strWindowsFolder & objChart.Name & ".png"
        Next objChart
        
        'chartobjects (on worksheets)
        For Each objSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            For Each objChartObject In objSheet.ChartObjects
                With objChartObject.Chart
                    .Export strWindowsFolder & .Name & ".png"
                End With
            Next
        Next
        
        'Open the windows folder
        Shell "Explorer.exe" & " " & strWindowsFolder, vbNormalFocus
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello! Sorry for the late reply. My charts are on chart sheets. Works great with this second loop, many thanks Tim! You saved me with your answer! :)